# How to use keyup and debouncer rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs

How would I utilize debounce to only trigger once the user has stopped typing? I have currently `keyup` triggering this function:

```ts
userTyping() {
    let searchTerm = this.form.get('query');
    searchTerm.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(1000)
      .subscribe(() => this.searchForUser());
  }
```

I basically don't want multiple queries to be started as you type say `james` in the search, only once the user stops typing for a certain time do I want it to fire.

Comment: Just write code for _valueChanges_ in `ngOnInit` or `constructor`

Comment: Could you explain to me why this would work?

Comment: Because you are subscribing to `valueChanges` (an Angular event) that will fire whenever value of the control has changed. In your case, whenever you type something, _valueChanges_ will fire and, after debouncing, the code inside _subscribe_ will execute. Checkout [this](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-valuechanges/) for example...

Comment: `debounceTime` is doing what you want already. It will cancel the previous scheduled value and create a new one. https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-xyvqnc?file=index.ts

Comment: Are you sure that you're not calling `userTyping()` method on every key press?

Comment: @martin thankyou for your insight, works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.userTyping()
  }
  userTyping() {
    let searchTerm = this.form.get('query');
    searchTerm.valueChanges.pipe().debounceTime(1000)
      .subscribe(() => this.searchForUser());
  }
```